# Need a java synchronization aid (something similar to ReentrantReadWriteLock)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Need a java synchronization aid similar to ReentrantReadWriteLock. But I want that acquired read lock can be released in another thread.

See code example with my comments:

```
public class Pool {

    // specific synchronization aid, which I want to find
    ReadWriteLock lock;

    public void acquire() {
        // increment count of readers, initial value for reader count = 0, 
        // possible reader count is unlimited
        lock.readerCountIncrement();
    }

    public void release() {
        // decrement count of readers
       lock.readerCountDecrement();
    }

    public void write() {
        // if method called, forbid (block on) readerCountIncrement() 
        // and wait until readers count become = 0
        lock.writeLockAcquire();
        try {
             // some actions
        } finally {
            // release and allow readerCountIncrement()
            lock.writeLockRelease();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any lock requires to be unlocked from the same thread which locks it. Such behavior is allowed by [semaphores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), but there is not read-write semaphore out-of-the box. You could implement any waiting behavior using [condition variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

Comment: "But I want that acquired read lock can be released in another thread." Your idea seems to be quite dangerous. A typical pattern of how to use a lock is to acquire it and then release in a finally block. How you can guarantee that the lock acquired by a reader thread will be released by another one? Are you sure this technique is the best way to address your problem?

Comment: In your example, where is the need to release locks acquired by another thread?